# Задача K Минимум в Полиноме

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, циклы, олимпиада

Вот такая задача на Нахождение K-ого минимума, написал такой код(На базовых примерах работает, на тестах все кроме 1 завалены): Помогите найти ошибку или исправить код пожалуйста

[image: Задача]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {



    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    uint64_t n = 0, k = 0, a = 0;
    vector<uint64_t> P(5000000);

    inp >> n >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        P[i] = 132 * pow((i+1), 3) + 77 * pow((i+1), 2) + 1345 * (i + 1) + 1577;
    }

    a = P[k] % 1743;

    otp << a;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Что значит фраза "k-ое в возрастающем порядке", и где это фигурирует в Вашем коде?

Comment: в `c++` есть `nth_element` в стандартной библиотеке.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку массив заполняется остатками по модулю,  нужно посмотреть, что даёт свойство модульного умножения. Например, для квадратичного члена

```
(a * x * x) mod M = ((a mod M) * (x mod M) * (x mod M)) mod M
```

Из этого следует, что остатки будут повторяться через каждые `М` чисел, и достаточно хранить M результатов. А надо ли хранить?

Для числа `N = q * M + r`:  `N-r` остатков будет повторяться `q` раз, а к остатков будет повторяться `q+1` раз.

Таки с образом, определяем для данного `N` параметры `q` и `r`, `A[1743]` инициируем нулями, затем делаем `r` шагов вычисления остатков по формуле,  складывая единицы в `A[остаток]`. Затем считаем сумму, пока она не превысит `k`- идём по списку, добавляя `q + A[i]` к сумме.

Пример для `(7*x+3) mod 5, N=8, K=5`

```
значения для x=1,2,3...  10  17  24  31  38  45  52  59
остатки                   0  2   4   1   3   0   2   4 

  0 1 2 3 4  //индексы A[i]
  --------------
  1 1 1 1 1   //это не считаем, а подразумеваем
  1   1   1   //посчитали 3 остатка (8 mod 5)   

  2 3 5       //сложили, пока не набралось k=5
```

Ответ - 2  (индекс, на котором накопили k=5)

проверяем: на 5 месте в сортированном списке остатков `0,0,1,2,2,3,4,4` идёт `2`

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko В ответе что-то непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется в виду `k`-тый локальный минимум:

```js
function calc(n, k, showArray) {
  var a = [1743];
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    a[i] = (132 * (i * i * i) + 77 * (i * i) + 1345 * i + 1577) % 1743;
  }
  a[a.length] = 1743;
 
  if (showArray)     
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));

  var minCounter = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if (a[i] < a[i - 1] && a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
      if (++minCounter == k) {
        return { index: i, value: a[i] };
      }
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log(10, i, JSON.stringify(calc(10, i, i == 1)));
}
console.log("for @pavel:", 4000000, 1234567, JSON.stringify(calc(4000000, 1234567)));
```

Как упражнение для читателя, оставлена задача оптимизации: совмещение двух циклов в один и выход из функции без вычисления всех `n` элементов массива.

Да, еще не учтен случай, когда минимум представляет собой площадку из нескольких точек.

*Код становится слишком длинным, чтобы уместиться на полях этой книги.*

---

Спокойствие. Те, кому свербит голосовать "против" из-за метки `с++` в вопросе, - голосуйте, я не боюсь ).

```
...
Бейте четыре-десять,
Не жалейте огня!

К.Симонов "Сын артиллериста"
```

Comment: кхм. мне кажется 4'000'000 искать будет ооочень долго.